# Unable to build a project with Eclipse and Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat

I'm newbie in Java and working on a project developed with this stack:

- Java 7
- Hibernate 3.5
- Struts 2.2
- Ireport 5.1

I installed Java 8, Eclipse (4.7.2) and Tomcat 8.5 in Windows 10. Now I'm simply trying to build and run the project but Eclipse shows me this error message (marker):

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.servlet.ServletContext. Fix the build path then try building this project

I have no idea from where to start. Someone can help me? Any information is welcome.

Comment: Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

The server libraries are missing. You have to choice targeted runtime for your Tomcat8.5.

**Project->Properties->Targeted Runtime**

If you don't have one you have to create new runtime environment
**Window->Server->Runtime Environment->Add Tomcat 8.5**

After that you can see in
**Project->Java Build Path->Libraries**

**Apache Tomcat v8.5** and probably you cannot see above error message